# How to compile a ts file to js in Angular and make it accessible in root when served?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I need my file firebase-messaging-sw.ts compiled to firebase-messaging-sw.js to be accessible from the root.

I already created firebase-messaging-sw.ts in the src folder. But that doesn't work. I also added the .js file in angular.json.

So what I want is to make a ts file and compile it to js. But I don't know how to do it in Angular.

angular.json

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js"
```

Comment: Do you want to write a TS file, or use an existing JS file ? You're not very clear ...

Comment: I'll edit my post I want to write a TS file and use the compiled js file

Comment: If you write a TS file and wire it right, the resulting JS file will automatically be imported to your bundle. You don't need any additional step.

Comment: I don't need it to be bundled I need it to be seperate js accessible like this http://test.org/firebase-messaging-sw.js

Comment: If it's separate then it can't be TS. If it's separate, it won't go through the build process, meaning that it should be JS.

Comment: What do you mean it can't be ts? What I want is write /a.ts compile to /a.js and make it accessible when it's served. I just need to know how to configure tsconfig or angular.json

Comment: Then you import your `a.ts` in your `main.ts` so that it gets bundled. You then have access to all of its variables in your components, either by importing it or by referencing the variable it has created.

Comment: No you don't understand. In order for firebase messaging to work. The browser needs a seperate js file in the root called firebase-messaging-sw.js It has be that specific file name and in the root.

Comment: Then create a JS file, not a TS file, and add it to your `angular.json`'s `scripts` array, in the correct one. I understood your issue, i've been answering it for 2 hours now. It's just that you don't seem to listen or understand what I'm saying.

Comment: I need to use environment variables from angular that's why I need t to be ts. So I don't think you understand the issue.

Comment: You can expose the environment variables to use them. And of course, if you don't state your goal, I can't understand the issue. You don't tell everything, how are we supposed to know ? Guess ? Like psychics ? But then again, I don't see why you should create a js file "at the root like this", libraries are supposed to abstract those concepts so that you don't have to do that exact thing you're trying to do. Seems like an XY issue to me.

Comment: You still don't fully understand. That file is REQUIRED to be in the root in order for firebase to work. It's a standard by all major browsers like Chrome Safari etc. I appreciate your time but it is what it is. I don't make the rules.

Comment: Could you please provide me the link to your library ?

Comment: Here is a guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it !

Comment: Thank you too man!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use

```
tsc myfile.ts
```

to compile a separate `.ts` file to a separate `.js` file, that has nothing to do with your Angular project.

Perhaps you can even run both commands at the same time in the terminal:

Terminal

```
tsc myfile.ts && ng build myproject
```

Or add it to package.json

```
"scripts":{
   "build" : "tsc myfile.ts && ng build myproject"
}

npm run build
```

Comment: This works but is it possible to configure this within a tsconfig file?

Comment: tsconfig allows for more options on how exactly to compile to js, but you still need tsc. But it might also be possible to add this process to Angular’s webpack file as a completely separate step

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't a good solution when the ts-file you're building depends on environments.ts vars. The correct dev/prod environments.ts is built after tsc has run.